# Kotlin Coroutines async and await in Splash Fragment

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I have a splash fragment and in this fragment i am getting user informations (getUserInfo) from internet. Also i have an basic animation in splash fragment. Here is my question. I want user to go to home page after gettingUserInformation so i use async and await(). When i am getting userInfo animation plays and go to homepage but i am not sure whether my code is correct or not. Which is the best way to do it.

```
        CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch{

            async { myViewModel.getUserInfo() }.await()

            val backgroundImg = binding.ivLogo
            val sideAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.slide)
            backgroundImg.startAnimation(sideAnimation)

            delay(1500)
            withContext(Dispatchers.Main){

                if ( onBoardingFinished()){
                    findNavController().navigate(SplashFragmentDirections.actionSplashFragmentToHomeFragment())
                }else {
                    findNavController().navigate(SplashFragmentDirections.actionSplashFragmentToViewPagerFragment())

                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: `async { myViewModel.getUserInfo() }.await()` is the same thing as `myViewModel.getUserInfo()`.

Comment: Use `lifecycleScope` instead of `CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO)` so you won't leak everything when the fragment is destroyed and/or recreated. You don't need to specify Dispatchers.IO anywhere here because none of the code in this coroutine is blocking.